# Create a subclass of list without deep copy

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I want to subclass `list` to add some function to it, for example, `my_func`.

Is there a way to do this without copying the whole list, i.e. make a shallow copy, on the creation of the `MyList` object and let `MyList` reference the same list as the one used to construct it?

```
class MyList(list):
    def my_func(self):
        # do some stuff
        return self


l1 = list(range(10))
l2 = MyList(l1)

print(l1)
print(l2)

l1[3] = -5

print(l1)
print(l2)
```

Comment: `l2 = l1` assignment does shallow copies in Python.  To do a deep copy, use `l2 = l1[:]`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  so wrong.  `l2 = l1[:]` is a shallow copy.  `l2 = l1` is not a copy at all, just another name bound to the same object.

Comment: @wim, it's all terminology. I would argue that `l2 = l1` is a (shallow) copy. Specifically, a copy of the list-pointer.

Comment: Sorry, no such thing as pointers in python.  It's all dicts underneath (names and objects).

Comment: @AaronMcDaid `l2 = l1` is as different from a shallow copy as a shallow copy is from a deep copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this isn't possible with a `list` subclass. It *is* possible with a **[`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList)** subclass (simply *[`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/userdict.html#module-UserList)* in Python `2`):

```
from collections import UserList

class MyList(UserList):

    def __init__(self, it=None):
        # keep reference only for list instances
        if isinstance(it, list):
            self.data = it
        else:
            super().__init__(it)

    def my_func(self):
        # do some stuff
        return self
```

The fact that `UserList` exposes a [**`data`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList.data) attribute containing the actual list instance makes it easy for us to replace it with the iterable `it` and essentially just drop the supplied argument there and *retain the reference*:

By initializing as you did:

```
l1 = list(range(10))
l2 = MyList(l1)

print(l1, l2, sep='\n')
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and then mutating:

```
l1[3] = -5
```

The `data` attribute referencing `l1` is, of course, mutated:

```
print(l1, l2, sep='\n')
[0, 1, 2, -5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, -5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Note for any python2 readers: It's not a py3-only feature, but you `import UserList` directly rather than from collections

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: According the py3 documentation `__init__` *must* be able to be called with zero or one arguments. ie. You must support `MyList()` as well as `MyList([1,2,3])`. After a little experimenting, it seems `UserList` handles all this for you by default, including transforming ranges and iterables into lists where necessary.

Comment: Also, see https://bugs.python.org/issue27639 for a bug with py3 version of `UserList` and getting slices.

Comment: @Dunes thanks, fixed that requirement. Yup, it handles instances other than `list` and `UserList` by [by wrapping them in a `list` call.](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l1034). Also, sneaky bug!